# When should and shouldn't I use "the" before the words "present", "past" and "future"?

Tags: definite-articles

When should and shouldn't I use *the* before the words *present, past* and *future*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be something subtle which some dictionaries will do a better job of explaining than others. However, the brute-force answer to the subtlety is that an article (whether definite or indefinite) identifies the following word as a noun.

Thus you should use an article when you are referring to *past, present* and *future* as **concepts in their own right.** Without the article, *past, present* and *future* **describe** something.

> **past**
>
> *noun* (**the past**): The time before the moment of speaking or writing
>   *adj:* Gone by in time and no longer existing
>
> [[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/past)]

> In **the past** (= In the time before now), there were more dinosaurs than mammals.
>   His past life (= his life he had lived up to now) was dissolute.

A similar distinction can be drawn for [*present*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/present) and [*future*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/future).

Note that it's also possible to speak of *a past, a future;* these refer to one possibility of many. And, because *past, present* and *future* are nouns, you can use possessives as well:

> He could see his future behind bars stretching before him. Or, by taking the red pill, a future of immense wealth.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. What is the difference between the following sentences ? 1. No body knows what will happen in the future. 2. No body knows what will happen in future.

Comment: One is a noun; the other is actually an adverbial phrase (which Oxford actually has in its entry: "from now onwards"). Please do consult dictionaries; I tend to favour Oxford, but there are [many others online](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available/2574#2574).